# Exclude objects from AWS S3 Inventory report

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket that contains millions of objects. I want to set up an AWS S3 inventory for that bucket. However, I want to exclude all objects inside the `test/` folder present at the bucket's root from the inventory report (CSV). There is an option in the console while configuring inventory which is:
`Prefix` which I think is a filter to include objects and not to exclude them.

How can I generate an inventory report of all bucket objects except the objects present inside the `test/` folder? Is there any way I can do this from the S3 Inventory console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is **no option to exclude a prefix**. You can use prefix to indicate inclusion, not exclusion. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html#storage-inventory-how-to-set-up):

> Amazon S3 inventory provides comma-separated values (CSV), Apache optimized row columnar (ORC) or Apache Parquet (Parquet) output files that list your objects and their corresponding metadata on a daily or weekly basis for an S3 bucket or a **shared prefix (that is, objects that have names that begin with a common string)**.

However, you could post process the inventory file with [Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html#storage-inventory-athena-query) to get only records you require:

> **Athena can query Amazon S3 inventory files** in ORC, Parquet, or CSV format. When you use Athena to query inventory, we recommend that you use ORC-formatted or Parquet-formatted inventory files.